# What do these action abbreviations mean?

Tags: terminology, pokertracker

I'm looking at some hands on Poker Tracker. What are the meanings of the following values in the "PF Act", "F Act", "T Act", "R Act" columns?

- C
- B
- XC
- F
- R
- CCF
- RF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each character stands for a single action. You can have more than one action for a single betting round, when someone bets or raises after you. These actions are combined into for example "XC" (first checked, then called) or "CCF" (called twice and finally folded).

- X = Check
- C = Call
- B = Bet
- R = Raise
- F = Fold

Answer (score 0):

The acts in the headings are actions for:

- PF = Pre flop
- F = Flop
- T = Turn; and
- R = River